# I can't tell which dev/sda/ file is my external hard drive to install Xubuntu on

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, windows, xubuntu

I want to install Xubuntu onto my external hard drive, but I cannot tell what partition to use. Here is what it shows

```
dev/sda
dev/sda1 ntfs
dev/sda2 ntfs
dev/sda3 ntfs
dev/sda4 fat32
```

`sda1-3` are [Windows 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8) files, but I don't know what the last one is, however I think it might be the hard drive, but I don't want to erase anything.

Answer (score 39):

The disk names in Linux are alphabetical. `/dev/sda` is the first hard drive (the primary master), `/dev/sdb` is the second etc. The numbers refer to partitions, so `/dev/sda1` is the first partition of the first drive.

It is likely that your external drive will not be `/dev/sda`, that is more likely to be the internal drive of your machine. To find out the name of your (attached) USB drive, run `sudo fdisk -l`.

Example output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x4b66b5d5

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63       80324       40131   de  Dell Utility
/dev/sda2   *       81920    30801919    15360000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        30801920   194643539    81920810    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       194643601   976773119   391064759+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       194643603   198836504     2096451    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda6       342951936   960387071   308717568   83  Linux
/dev/sda7       198840320   342949887    72054784   83  Linux
/dev/sda8       960389120   976773119     8192000   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x484882da

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1              63   976768064   488384001    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

That command will list all partitions of all connected drives, it will probably include some `/dev/sdbX` partitions as well and those are the ones you want. In the output above, my external USB drive is `sdb` and has the partition `sdb1`.

You can also see the device name of your USB drive with `lsblk`:

```
$ lsblk 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  39.2M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0  14.7G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0  78.1G  0 part /winblows
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0     2G  0 part 
├─sda6   8:6    0 294.4G  0 part /home
├─sda7   8:7    0  68.7G  0 part /
└─sda8   8:8    0   7.8G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 465.8G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Again, in the example above, `sdb` is my external USB drive.

Comment: My external USB drive is indeed `/dev/sda`.  The internal drive of my machine is `/dev/nvme0n1`.

Comment: Same here. It is possible for secondary and external hard drives to be named `sda`

Comment: Yes, these are probably laptops with internal nvme SSD drives. Those weren't very common when this answer was written, they have become much more common now.

Answer (score 7):

`/dev/sda` it's 100% your internal drive. Your external drive may be sdb, sdc or another one.

To list your drives try: `sudo parted -l` to list all drives and information about them.

Answer (score 1):

Run `udevadm monitor` and plug in your drive. This will tell you where your drive is at in the dev directory.

For example, one of the output lines from plugging in a USB drive on my PC (partition ID in bold):

```
KERNEL[90052.302744] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sdd/sdd1 (block)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load Xubuntu from a live CD (or USB) and launch gParted to check wich partition is the right one.

You can create a liveUSB using http://www.linuxliveusb.com/

You'll probably want to format your partition (or your drive) to a ext3 or ext4 though.

Answer (score 0):

Any and all media that is "External" will be dev/sdb! Any and all media that is "Internal" will be dev/sda