# How to tell which device the USB drive is assigned as?

Tags: command-line, usb, live-usb, usb-drive

How can I tell which device the USB drive is assigned as?

Before inserting the USB drive:

```
$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1     259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p5 259:3    0  15.9G  0 part [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0 222.6G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0     1K  0 part
```

After:

```
$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    1   1.9G  0 disk 
├─sda2        8:2    1   2.4M  0 part 
└─sda1        8:1    1   1.2G  0 part 
nvme0n1     259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p5 259:3    0  15.9G  0 part [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0 222.6G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0     1K  0 part
```

Is it `/dev/sda`??

Comment: Hi teelou, posted my answer, please mention if all is clear or not.

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/425767/295286

Comment: Also relevant https://askubuntu.com/q/27997/295286

Comment: You don't need to repeat the output that was in one of the answers. Just accepting the answer will do :). Better to separate answer / question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply use `lsblk` output options to find it out:

```
lsblk -o NAME,TRAN
```

which produces:

```
sda                    sata
├─sda1
└─sda2           
sdb                    usb
└─sdb1                 
sr0                    sata
```

You can also use other options to get extra information (e.g: SIZE).
If you want a nice clean output use `-S`:

```
$ lsblk -So NAME,SIZE,TRAN

NAME   SIZE  TRAN
sda    400G  sata
sdb    16G   usb
sr0    1024M sata
```

Answer (score 4):

#### How to find out which of your devices is a usb device

*In short*:

```
find /dev/disk -ls | grep usb
```

Or, on a specific device:

```
find /dev/disk -ls | grep usb | grep sda
```

If it has any output, `sda` is a usb device.

#### Long version

Information on your devices is to be found in the directory `/dev/disk`. Specifically the sub directories `/dev/disk/by-id` and `/dev/disk/by-path` give us information on wheter a device is a usb device or not. For example a name like:

```
usb-0930_USB_Flash_Memory_04506470B2D398CF-0:0
```

makes clear this is a usb drive.

If I run `ls -l` on the file, the output is:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 apr 27 09:21 /dev/disk/by-id/usb-0930_USB_Flash_Memory_04506470B2D398CF-0:0 -> ../../sdb
```

which clearly shows this is `sdb`

#### Using find to filter out usb devices

The `find ... -ls` command, will subsequently give us the information we need.

You can easily find out which of the devices is a usb device by running the command:

```
find /dev/disk -ls | grep usb
```

To check if specifically `sda` is a usb device, run:

```
find /dev/disk -ls | grep usb | grep sda
```

If it has any output, it is a usb device.

It obviously looks like your usb device has two partitions:

```
sda           8:0    1   1.9G  0 disk 
├─sda2        8:2    1   2.4M  0 part 
└─sda1        8:1    1   1.2G  0 part
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the syslog (`/var/log/syslog`) and `dmesg` right after connecting the USB should show messages about what `/dev/sXY` device it is, or if it had any problems and didn't get a `/dev/sXY` name.

Looking at `lsblk` should match it by size, if it successfully got a /dev/ name and you're sure there are no other similar sized devices attached.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is looking at the output of `blkid` (optionally executed as root, i.e. as `sudo blkid`). This will give you the opportunity to match your device not only by size but also by file system and/or partition label. Especially the partion label can be quite helpful.

Going by the output from `lsblk` you posted, it is quite obvious that your USB device actually is `sda`. You have one block device, then you connect your USB device, and it now shows two devices. So, obviously, the additional device appeared upon plugging in your USB device, so it should be the same device.