# bootable USB-live - 0+0 records in?

Tags: live-usb, usb-drive

Why am I not able to make an USB-live?

I am trying to make a bootable USB-live from http://www.memtest86.com/download.htm

This is what I do on my terminal:

```
$ lsblk
$ cd ~/Downloads
$ sudo dd if=memtest86-usb.img of=/dev/sda bs=1M;sudo sync;sudo eject /dev/sda
```

But what I get is:

```
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0.000149567 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that /dev/sda is correct? That's usually your primary hard disk.

Comment: @AndroidDev I think so. I wasn't sure before but see my question here https://askubuntu.com/questions/909346/how-to-tell-which-device-the-usb-drive-is-assigned-as

Comment: Your command string doesn't care if `dd` fails or succeeds, using `&&` instead of `;` should only proceed if successful. I don't think there's a difference between `sudo sync` and plain `sync`, and `eject` is usually used for "*CD-ROM, floppy disk, tape, or JAZ or ZIP disk*", does it do anything for a USB? Mine doesn't

Comment: Also, all the standard Ubuntu live ISO's have memtest included, you can run it from there. And is the .img file really in ~/Downloads?

Comment: @Xen2050 `And is the .img file really in ~/Downloads? ` yes sure it is.  how can i use the memtest included in Ubuntu live ISO? I am using Kubuntu.

Comment: Wasn't sure if dd would complain, apparently it does for "no such file" & "permission denied". It will happily copy an empty file, and output just like yours, might as well post that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

I think your .img file is empty (or there's something wrong with it), that's exactly what `dd` says when you tell it to read an empty file:

```
$ touch empty
$ dd if=empty of=e2
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 0.000555823 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

---

The Ubuntu live ISO's should have a copy of memtest, under the "Test memory" entry in their menu, similar to this image (at least the used to, haven't booted a "raw" live iso in a while):

[image]

Comment: I downloaded and extracted memtest86-usb.img in order to see what's in it. memtest86-usb.img is a 157.3 MB file. I could mount it and open several files in it after it was mounted, so I don't think it's an empty file or else something may be wrong with it. If you download it yourself and mount it, this will provide a better explanation than anything else I could say in a comment.

Comment: @karel I'm not sure why else `dd` would act like it's an empty file, maybe teelou had something go wrong with their download and their copy's empty